# How to use an IO completion port with QOSNotifyFlow

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, qos

I'm writing a program with sockets and I need QoS services so I'm using `qWAVE`. Now I want to be able to detect network changes and adapt to it, so based on documentations I should use `QOSNotifyFlow`. While its design is great for one or 2 sockets, when you have multiple sockets that each one(group) of them have different characteristics, so added to different flow, you can't use `OVERLAPPED` structure easily(`WaitForMultipleObjects...` have a hard coded limitation).

So I was searching for an alternative way that does not use waiting for the overlapped event to signalled and I found [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f0a2181-28ae-4d07-a0cf-68a4e8b55fad/questions-about-qosnotifyflow?forum=networkqosqwave) that ask a similar question and an `MSFT` answer him that he may use an IO completion port.

Now my question is can I use something like IO completion port with this kind of functions that get an `OVERLAPPED` structure?